# Memory can't be read when shortest function is run

Tags: c

I had a bunch of problems with this program but looks like this might be inches away from completion and I was hoping someone could tell me what the hell's wrong with the blasted thing!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE_OF_STRING 21

void displayMenu(void);
void readArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);       
void printArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);
int shortestArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);
int smallestArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);
void sortArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);

int main(void)
{
    int position, n = 0;    /*  all local to main */
    char select[10];    /*  select is a string */
    char array[1000][SIZE_OF_STRING];   

    displayMenu();
    scanf("%s", select);    /* read first selection */

    while (strcmp(select, "exit") != 0) /* while not exit */
    {
        if (strcmp(select, "read") == 0)
        {
            printf("How many names?");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            n++;
            printf("Enter %d names", n - 1);
            readArray(array, n);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "display") == 0)
        {
            printArray(array, n);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "shortest") == 0)
        {
            position = shortestArray(array, n);
            printf("Shortest name is %s in position %d\n", array[position], position + 1);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "lowest") == 0)
        {
            position = smallestArray(array, n);
            printf("Lowest name is %s in position %d\n", 
            array[position], position + 1);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "sort") == 0)
        {
            sortArray(array, n);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID SELECTION");
        }

        displayMenu();
        scanf("%s", select);    /* read next selection */
    } /* end  while */
}/* end  main */

void displayMenu(void)
{
    puts("Menu selection");
    puts("Enter read to read names");
    puts("Enter display to display names");
    puts("Enter shortest for shortest name");
    puts("Enter lowest for lowest names");
    puts("Enter sort to sort names");
    puts("Enter exit to exit\n");
}

void readArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\ntype one string per line\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        gets(a[i]);
    }
}   

void printArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\ntype one string per line\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        puts(a[i]);
    }
}

int shortestArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    int i;
    int chag = 0;
    int position; 
    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (strlen(a[i]) < strlen(a[i-1]))
        {
            position = i; 
            chag = 1; 
        }
        else
        { 
            if (chag = 0)
            {
                position = 1; 
            }
            else
            {
                printf("");
            }
        } 
    }

    return position; 

}

int smallestArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    puts("Not yet implemented\n");
    return 0;
}

void sortArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n) 
{
    puts("Not yet implemented\n");
}
```

only worried about "shortest" function at the moment all others run okay.

I also know there are better ways of doing the search but I keep getting "declaration creates integer from pointer without cast" errors when I change to a more standard search with a default smallest etc.

chag is to say whether or not number one in `a[]` is the smallest as it never gets checked, going to change this as soon as I get it working as I can see a more effective way of doing it.

[edit]
My bad, the error that appears is an application error when "smallest" is selected. 
 the following appears

```
"the instruction at "0x77c478c0" referenced memory at "0xd2fd82e0". the memory could not be "read". 

ok to terminate program, cancel to debug.
```

changed the shortest function to the following and still get a similar memory message;

```
int shortestArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    int i = 1;
    int position = 1; 

    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (strlen(a[i + 1]) < strlen(a[i]))
        {
            position = i + 1; 
            i++;
        }
        else
        {     
            i++;  
        }
    }

    return position; 
}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is...

Comment: `i` being `0` and `a[i-1]` probably won't play nice.

Comment: Are you compiling with all warnings and paying attention to all warnings?

Comment: Please provide only the offending code, the error message and the line where the error occurred.

Answer (score 4):

There's a clbuttic typo in `shortestArray()`:

```
if (chag = 0) {
               position = 1; 
               }
// ...
```

This will always evaluate to false, so the `else` block is run.

Here, zero is *assigned* to `chag` which makes the expression evaluate to zero (false). Use the comparision operator `==` instead. You might want to crank up warning levels as I'm sure, any C compiler has an appropriate message for this.

Answer (score 4):

One big and obvious problem is that in the function you use the variable `i` without initializing it.

Another problem is this expression: `strlen(a[i-1])`. If `i` is 0 then this will access memory *before*  the array.

Comment: ...and if it is initialized to 0 then a[i-1] won't be good... and that i is never incremented/decremented.

Comment: changed this, now we seem to be getting somewhere! However it now just freezes (more just kind of stops) when I select shortest.

Comment: @ThomasHedley Like Sani said, you have to increase `i` as well in the loop. Also, are you sure that there will be an entry in the array that is an empty string, so the loop will stop?

Comment: I think I've fixed it (in terms of the actual code looking like it should now), although I'm still getting the same kind of memory message, not sure what you mean by empty string... do you mean a nul so that the while stops?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers so far:

- You don't increment `i` either.
- If I imagine all the trivial fixes applied (correct iteration, comparison instead of assignment in the condition), the function is going to return position of last local minimum of length. I.e. having list of strings like

  ```
  "a", "bbbb", "ccc", "dd"
  ```

  it will return 3, but shortest string is at position 0!
- You do remember array indices in C start from 0, right (in `position = 1`)?

Comment: how can you answer a question with a question? oh yeah! that's right, by acting like a smart ass. No need to be sarcastic mate, I'm only a beginner. think I'd better add that your answer was of no use... whatsoever.

Comment: I am not trying to be sarcastic. I am just asking whether `position = 1` is mistake caused by confusing 0 and 1-based indices or intention. For what it's worth it might have been intention, but it does not seem likely.

Answer (score -1):

you have to know the number of strings entered in the array to avoid unknown behavior.
a way to do this : in main, just after declaration of array, put :

```
strcpy(array[0], ""); // to indicate that the array is empty.
```

in the end of readArray() :

```
strcpy(a[n] , ""); // there is n strings written bythe user (a[0] to a[n-1]).
```

and finally :

in shortestArray(), the stop condition of the loop must be changed to :

```
while (strcmp(a[i],"") != 0 ) //a[i] == '\0' is not correct because a[i] is string and '\0' is char.
```

here is the entire code with the changes i made :

```
       #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE_OF_STRING 21
#define SIZE_OF_ARRAY 1000

void displayMenu(void);
void readArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);       
void printArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING]);
int shortestArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING]);
int smallestArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);
void sortArray(char [][SIZE_OF_STRING], int);

int main(void)
{
    int position, n = 0;    /*  all local to main */
    char select[10];    /*  select is a string */
    char array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY][SIZE_OF_STRING]; //change here !
    strcpy(array[0] , ""); //instruction added : means array is empty 

    displayMenu();
    scanf("%s", select);    /* read first selection */

    while (strcmp(select, "exit") != 0) /* while not exit */
    {
        if (strcmp(select, "read") == 0)
        {
            printf("How many names?");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            while (n >= SIZE_OF_ARRAY)
            {
                printf("the number you entered is bigger than the maximum number of strings, please enter a number smaller than %d\n", SIZE_OF_ARRAY); 
            }


            printf("Enter %d names", n);
            readArray(array, n);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "display") == 0)
        {
            printArray(array);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "shortest") == 0)
        {
            position = shortestArray(array);
            if (position == -1)
                printf("there is no string entered !\n"); 
            else
                printf("Shortest name is %s in position %d\n", array[position-1], position );
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "lowest") == 0)
        {
            position = smallestArray(array, n);
            printf("Lowest name is %s in position %d\n", 
                array[position], position + 1);
        }
        else if (strcmp(select, "sort") == 0)
        {
            sortArray(array, n);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("INVALID SELECTION");
        }

        displayMenu();
        scanf("%s", select);    /* read next selection */
    } /* end  while */
}/* end  main */

void displayMenu(void)
{
    puts("Menu selection");
    puts("Enter read to read names");
    puts("Enter display to display names");
    puts("Enter shortest for shortest name");
    puts("Enter lowest for lowest names");
    puts("Enter sort to sort names");
    puts("Enter exit to exit\n");
}

void readArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("\ntype one string per line\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",a[i]);
    }
    strcpy(a[n] , "");
}   

void printArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i< SIZE_OF_ARRAY; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(a[i] , "") == 0) // a[i-1] is last string entered
            break;              // this avoid printing non initialized string causing unknown behaviour.
        printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    }
}

int shortestArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING])
{
    int i = 0;
    int position = 1; 
    if(strcmp (a[i] , "\0") == 0)
        return position = -1;  // there no string entered.

    while (strcmp (a[i+1] , "\0") != 0)
    {
        if (strlen(a[i+1]) < strlen(a[i]))
        {
            position = i+2 ; 
            i++;
        }
        else
        {     
            i++;  
        }
    }

    return position; 
}

int smallestArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n)
{
    puts("Not yet implemented\n");
    return 0;
}

void sortArray(char a[][SIZE_OF_STRING], int n) 
{
    puts("Not yet implemented\n");
}
```

Comment: The initial value of position isn't a problem. It's just weird to return 1 if there are no entries.

Comment: Never answer questions tagged "homework" with complete solution, especially without explanation of *why* it should be like that (yes, the function is correct, but it's very far from the original)

Comment: this code makes it all pretty failsafe... still doesn't work.

Comment: you also broke display... not sure how but you did. reverting back to my old crappy code now.

Comment: if I print a[1] I get the first thing I entered, i.e. what you guys are saying should be at a[0] must have changed somewhere.

Comment: Thomas Hedley : "you also broke display... not sure how but you did. reverting back to my old crappy code now", now, it is fixed (i misused the return of strcmp()). you know, your code is not crappy, it was good but needs some corrections.